# Prove that the function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $[0,\infty)$
>
> there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x) - (ax +b)] =0$
>
> prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,\infty)$

how i started:

using that function limit definition:
let $\epsilon >0$
there is a $M>$ such that for every $x>M, |f(x) - (ax +b)|<\epsilon$
in the interval $[0,M]$
the function is uniformly continuous (by weierstrass theorem).

this is there part i got stuck in, i know that f(x) "Converges" with the $(ax+b)$,
but i cant find a $\delta$ that will prove what i need

Comment: Sloppy outline: Let $\epsilon>0$. If you choose $M$ so that $|f(x)-(ax+b)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>M$, then using the triangle inequality, you can show, for $x,y>M$, that $|f(x)-f(y)|<3\epsilon$ with an additional constraint on $x$ and $y$ (namely $|a||x-y|<\epsilon$). Now find a $0<\delta<1$ that "works" for $x,y\in[0,M+1]$. Then put the pieces together.

Answer (score 2):

As $g(x)=ax+b$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ and the sum of uniformly contnuous functions is also a uniformly continuous function, we can assume that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0.
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $M>0$, such that whenever
$x\ge M$, then $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/3$. As $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,M]$, then there exists a $\delta>0$, such that for $x,y\in [0,M]$
$$
|x-y|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.
$$
Now let $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ with $|x-y|<\delta$.

Case I. $x,y\in [0,M]$, then clearly $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/3<\varepsilon$.

Case II. $x,y>M$, then $|f(x)|, |f(y)|<\varepsilon/3$ and hence $|f(x)-f(y)|<2\varepsilon/3<\varepsilon$.

Case III. $x<M<y$. Then 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f(M)|+|f(M)-f(y)|\le \varepsilon/3+2\varepsilon/3=\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: $$
\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0.
$$ this isn't necessarily true...

Comment: @yiorgos S.Smyrlis very nice argument. complete one.

Comment: @guynaa: What do you not agree with?

Comment: $f(x)$ can easily go to infinity if $a$ is not $0$

Comment: @guynaa: That's not a problem. $g(x)=ax+b$ is uniformly continuous for every $a\in\mathbb R$, since $|g(x)-g(y)|=|a||x-y|$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis, can you make it more clear: Why we can assume $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$?

Comment: @Elimination: Because we consider the difference $g(x)=f(x)-ax-b$.